# Plus equal misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, console

I'm trying something in my browser and I don't understand the result.

When I type :

```
var testPlus = 0;
testPlus += 2
console.log(testPlus)
```

It gives testPlus = 2.

But when I type

```
var testPlus = 0;
(testPlus +=2) * 2;
console.log(testPlus)
```

It still gives 2, like if "*2" weren't calculated. 
I don't get why ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only assigning the `+2` back to `testPlus`. The `*2` is happening, but the answer is not being stored anywhere.

So, `(testPlus +=2) * 2;` bumps up **the value being stored in `testPlus`** to `2` and then that is multiplied by `2`, creating a value of `4`. But, that `4` isn't used or stored anywhere.

Comment: @Ferdinand No problem. Don't forget to mark as the answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In the statement

```
(testPlus +=2) * 2
```

The portion in parentheses is evaluated first. That adds `2` to the variable. Only then, after the addition *and* after the variable is updated, is the value multiplied by `2`.

If your intention is to update `testPlus` to equal its value plus `2` and then multiplied by `2`, you can't do that with `+=`:

```
testPlus = (testPlus + 2) * 2;
```

Or you could use a sequence of two statements, one with `+=` and one with `*=`:

```
testPlus += 2;
testPlus *= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never using the result of the expression. You multiplied (the changed) `testPlus` value by 2, and then thrown it away. Compare `testPlus + 2` and `testPlus = testPlus + 2` (`testPlus += 2` is a shortcut for that).